# Disable MouseWheel in editable ComboBox as ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, combobox, listbox, mousewheel, itemtemplate

I use a ComboBox as ItemTemplate inside a ListBox. My ComboBox is editable. When the user use the mouse wheel in the combobox, it change the current value. I don't want that. I want the ListBox to scroll. Is there any solution to this ?
Most examples I found are based only on a readonly ComboBox. 
It seems that none of the solution I found works.
override OnMouseWheel setting isHandled = true does not work
it seems the event is handled in other places. I tried to override OnMouseWheel in
the TextBox used by the ControlTemplate of my ComboBox without success.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 11):

Okay, my mistake, I put PreviewMouseWheel on a wrong UIElement of my ItemTemplate.
So this is working:

```
private void myCombo_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Nevertheless, the "parentListBox.RaiseEvent(args);" does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I solved your problem with a Behavior (and the logic provided by @XamlZealot):

```
internal class ComboBoxIsNotScrollingItemsBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += this.ComboBox_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= this.ComboBox_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    private void ComboBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            ((FrameworkElement)this.AssociatedObject.Parent).RaiseEvent(new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
            {
                RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
                Source = sender
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue once with the following approach:

WPF:

```
<ComboBox MouseWheel="ComboBox_MouseWheel"/>
```

C#:

```
private void ComboBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    MouseWheelEventArgs args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
    args.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
    args.Source = sender;
    parentListBox.RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

Comment: this does not work with editable combobox. I don't even get into the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering a class handler in your constructor:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ComboBox), ComboBox.MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MouseWheeled));

private void MouseWheeled(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MouseWheelEventArgs mouseArgs = (MouseWheelEventArgs)e;
    e.Handled = true;
    MouseWheelEventArgs args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(mouseArgs.MouseDevice, mouseArgs.Timestamp, mouseArgs.Delta);
    args.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
    args.Source = Sender;
    parentListBox.RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

Comment: PreviewMouseWheel do the trick but this is not working with my combobox styles. If I test on a simple project, the mouse wheel is properly disabled.

Comment: damned, this is working outside of my project, with my styles ! I don't understand why this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to say our case is like, Font list box in toolbar: choosing a new font where previously selected font is still appear as the selected value, yet you could scroll vertically?

In that case can you consider a sample like this? [creating a Font Box](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fontdialog) as well.

Further reference:
Could you check on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511458.aspx)?